# How do you get S3 methods to work with S4 objects?

Tags: oop, r, r-s3, r-s4

I'm writing an S3 method that I want to work with *any* R object, including S4 objects.

The first thing I don't understand is that S4 classes don't appear to derive from an S4 base class, so given `f <- function(x) UseMethod("f")` I can't just declare an `f.S4` dispatch method and have it pick up all S4 objects.  (Although if you `unclass` an S4 object, it does seem to be given class `S4`.)  How should I manage the dispatching?

It seems that the easiest way to deal with these S4 objects would be to convert them to be lists.  Unfortunately, `as.list` throws an error ("no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector").

This is my test S4 object:

```
library(gWidgetstcltk)
win <- gwindow()
```

The functions `S3Part` and `S3Class` in the `methods` package looked promising, but they both throw errors when I use them on `win`.  So, question 2 is: Is there a general way of converting S4 objects to lists?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

S4 is a superclass (virtual class, whatever, somebody please chime in with the correct name) that cannot be used directly dispatching. Same for S3 by the way. You can do S3-dispatching for S4 classes the way you do with S3 classes. On a sidenote, if nothing is specified then calling `myfun` on an S4 object will just lead to the .default function. :

```
myfun <- function(object, ...) UseMethod("myfun")

myfun.default <- function(object,...){
    cat("default method.\n")
    print(object)
}

myfun.gWindow <- function(object,...){
    cat("Here here...")
    print(object)
}

x <- 1:10
myfun(x)
myfun(win)
rm(myfun.gWindow)
myfun(win)
```

If you want to catch all S4 methods, you can dispatch manually in your .default function or generic function, using `isS4()`. Adding the dispatching in the .default function allows for automatic S3 dispatching to some S4 classes. If you add it in the generic, you just dispatch to all S4 no-matter-what :

```
    myfun.default <- function(object,...){
        if(isS4(object)) myfun.S4(object,...)
        else {
          cat("default method.\n")
          print(object)
        }
    }

    myfun.S4 <- function(object,...){
        cat("S4 method\n")
        print(object)
    }

x <- 1:10
myfun(x)
myfun(win)
```

Regarding your second question: `gWindow` is a special case. It also returns an error when tried with `str(win)`. I don't know the exact structure, but it's definitely not a normal S4 object.

Comment: Thanks.  The dispatching makes much more sense now. Looks like I stumbled upon a tricky test case; will have to try a few others and investigate further.

Comment: The gwindow object is indeed a bad example. I believe the length method I define for gWidgets objects messes up str. The gwindow object has two slots one to hold a toolkit (which gWidgetsXXX package to  use for method dispatch) and another for an object from the gWidgetsXXX package. However, Joris is showing what to do. There is a superclass for gWindow that one can use to catch others.

Comment: @John: Thanks for the clarification. I'll concentrate on solving the easier cases first.